# manage.py loaddata hangs when loading to remote postgres

Tags: python, django, django-south

I am trying to migrate django models from sqlite to postgres. I tested it locally and now trying to do the samething with remote database. I dumped the data first then started the application which created the tables in remote database.

Finally I am trying to loaddata but it looks like hanged and no errors.

Is there a way to get verbose ? Or I am not sure how to diagnose this issue. It just 199M size file and when I test locally loaddata works in few minutes.

Comment: Why not scp the file to the remote server and load it from there and avoid network flakiness?

Answer (score 1):

I had no solution, so I ran loaddata locally and used pg_dump and ran the dump with pqsl -f and restored the data.